# QSqlQuery works wrong

Tags: database, postgresql, qt

There are some QSqlQuery examples. I think these examples must work in the same manner. I investigated this code with GDB and Wireshark (I watched which queries was submitted to PostgreSQL server).

**Example 1**

The database connect code fragments are omitted.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.open();
QSqlQuery q(db);
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.bindValue(":user_name", "gagarin");
q.exec();
```

This sample works perfectly. When `prepare` method is invoked, the query has got text identifier, and this identifier and parametrized query has been submitted to the server. When `exec` method is invoked, the query identifier and vector of parameters is sent to the server. The server returned query result successfully.

**Example 2**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
QSqlQuery q(db);
db.open();
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.bindValue(":user_name", "gagarin");
q.exec();
```

This sample works wrong. Despite QSqlQuery constructor has got not yet opened database, the real database parameters is being stored in global workspace, and QSqlQuery takes them by connection name, Thus there is no difference whether I  open connection before of after QSqlQuery constructor invoking. So, let's watch the code behavior. `prepare` method invoking has no effect. When `exec` method is invoked, this rubbish is sent to the server:

```
SELECT * FROM get_person('gagarin'
```

Therefore, the server cannot return data. If the query didn't have parameters, like query of view, it would be executed, but it would be submitted on `exec` invoking, but not `prepare` invoking. It's wrong.

**Example 3**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
QSqlQuery q(db);
db.open();
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.addBindValue("gagarin");
q.exec();
```

In this case `prepare` method invoking has no effect also. And on `exec` invoking query has been built without mistakes. This is a query sent to the server:

```
SELECT * FROM get_person('gagarin')
```

Server successfully returns query result. Nevertheless, it's a wrong behavior, because query text should be sent to the server on `prepare` invoking, and on `exec` - the query identifier and vector of parameters only.

So, what is this, bug or feature?

Version of Qt - 5.6.1.

The `prepare` method returned true in all examples.

Comment: The docs state: [`Warning: You must load the SQL driver and open the connection before a QSqlQuery is created. Also, the connection must remain open while the query exists; otherwise, the behavior of QSqlQuery is undefined.`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#details)

Comment: Of course, writing a warning is easier than fix a bug. Answer is accepted.